# Checking if a string is composed of 3 capital letters and 4 numbers (in JAVA)

Tags: java, string

I need to check if a string is composed by 3 capital letters and 4 digits.

For example: ABC1234

OBS: Without using regular expressions?

This is what I have tried so far. Thanks!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String input  = "ABC1234"; 
String firstThreeChars = ""; //substring containing first three characters
String lastFourChars = ""; //substring containing last four characters

if (input.length() > 4) {
  firstThreeChars = input.substring(0, 3);
}

if (input.length() > 4) {
  lastFourChars = input.substring(input.length() - 4);
}

System.out.println(firstThreeChars);
System.out.println(lastFourChars);
```

}

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You should focus on a specific programming problem when asking a question on Stack Overflow, not how to implement an entire program or feature. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), the site tour, and especially [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) Once you do, you should edit your question to improve it so that it can be considered for re-opening.

Comment: Your question currently seems to ask Stack Overflow to write the entire solution for you.  Have you written a Java program before?  Do you know how to loop through the characters of a String?  Do you know how to declare and increment a counter variable?  Do you know how to check whether a character is a capital letter or a digit?  Showing us what you have already tried will answer these questions.

Comment: Sorry folks! It was my first time posting a question here. I'm gonna edit the question and post what I've done so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the letters and numbers are in random places in the string.

---

Just use two counters and count.

```
if (input.length != 7) {
    System.out.println("No");
    return;
}


int letterCount = 0, digitCount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
    char c = input.charAt(i);
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
        ++letterCount;
    } else if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
        ++digitCount;
    } else {
        System.out.println("No");
        return;
    }
}

if (letterCount == 3 && digitCount == 4) {
    System.out.println("Yes");
} else {
    System.out.println("No");
}
```

Comment: Ow great!! That's a start, but unfortunately that just count the numbers of letters and digits. But I need to check if the **first 3**characters are letters and the last four are numbers. For example: if the user's input is "ABC1234" it's not the same as "1234ABC", but still it's gonna count 3 letters and 4 digits..but thanks anyway ;)

Comment: When you've separated the string in 3 + 4 letters, check each string with a `for` loop.